# Make 2 mysql rows into 1 in where

Tags: php, mysql

So basicly im coding a search page where people search for people
Every account has 2 rows for their names eg. John Doe is stored into 2 rows in people table firstname = John and lastname = Doe
So my question is when i search for someone when they type John it will return John Doe but if someone types in the full name "John Doe" it will return nothing 
So how could i merge 2 rows the firstname and lastname into one like this

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT firstname,lastname FROM people WHERE firstname AND     lastname = '$searchquery'");
```

This above is just an example of how i need it to be

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you make a user have two rows to store first and last name instead of one row that has those two columns?

Comment: "John Doe" is stored in two rows?  You then describe the data as having the fields in two columns.  Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT_WS`. Try this:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT firstname,lastname FROM people WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname, lastname) = '$searchquery'");
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can merge strings, like this:

```
SELECT firstname,lastname FROM people WHERE CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) = '$searchquery'
```

You can also try this:

```
SELECT firstname,lastname FROM people WHERE '$searchquery' LIKE CONCAT('%',firstname,'%',lastname,'%')
```